# When do we have $\liminf_{n\to\infty}(a_n+b_n)=\liminf_{n\to\infty}(a_n)+\liminf_{n\to\infty}(b_n)$?

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

It's not hard to show that
 $$\liminf_{n\to\infty}(a_n+b_n)\geq\liminf_{n\to\infty}(a_n)+\liminf_{n\to\infty}(b_n)$$
for any $\{a_n\},\{b_n\}\subset{\Bbb R}$ such that the right hand side is defined (i.e. no $\infty-\infty$ or $-\infty+\infty$). Also, if both $\lim a_n$ and $\lim b_n$ exist, then we have
$$
\liminf_{n\to\infty}(a_n+b_n)=\liminf_{n\to\infty}(a_n)+\liminf_{n\to\infty}(b_n). 
$$

The wikipedia article about [limit inferior and limit superior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior) gives a sufficient conditions for "$=$" to hold which I don't see how to prove it:

> if one of $\lim a_n$ and $\lim b_n$ exists, then we have "$=$".

Here are my questions:

> - How can I show the statement above?
> - Is this condition also necesarry?

---

Assume for example $\lim a_n=a$. To show
$$
\liminf_{n\to\infty}(a_n+b_n)=a+\liminf_{n\to\infty}(b_n),
$$
it suffices to show that
$$
\liminf_{n\to\infty}(a_n+b_n)\leq\liminf_{n\to\infty}(a_n)+\liminf_{n\to\infty}(b_n)
$$
I think somehow I would need to use $\liminf_{n\to\infty}(a_n)=\limsup_{n\to\infty}(a_n)=a$. But I don't see how this works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Equality:** I will use the most convenient characterization of $\liminf x_n$ as the least limit in $[-\infty,+\infty]$ of all converging subsequences of $x_n$ (including the infinity cases, where I would say, tend, rather than converge).

Take a subsequence $b_{n_k}$ of $b_n$ which tends to $\liminf b_n$. Then 
$$\lim_k a_{n_k}+b_{n_k}= \lim_k a_{n_k}+\lim_k b_{n_k}=\lim a_n +\liminf b_n.$$ 
So $\liminf (a_n+b_n)\leq \lim a_n +\liminf b_n$.

Now take a subsequence $a_{n_k}+b_{n_k}$ of $a_n+b_n$ which tends to $\liminf (a_n+b_n)$. Then 
$$\lim_k b_{n_k}=\lim_k (a_{n_k}+b_{n_k})-a_{n_k}=\liminf (a_n+b_n)-\lim a_n.$$
So $\liminf b_n\leq \liminf (a_n+b_n)-\lim a_n$.

This proves the desired equality.

**Non equivalence:**  For instance
$$
\liminf (-1)^n+(-1)^n=-2=(-1)+(-1)=\liminf (-1)^n+\liminf (-1)^n.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Simply 
$$\liminf_{n\to\infty} (b_n)=
\liminf_{n\to\infty}(a_n-a+b_n)=\liminf_{n\to\infty} (a_n+b_n)-a
$$

Note that in the first equality $|a_n-a|$ can be made less than $\varepsilon$ for sufficiently

large $n$   $\clubsuit$

Comment: How do you justify the first equality? That's essentially what your asked to prove.

Comment: $a_n-a $ converges to $0$..

Comment: So LHS can't be even epsilon greater..

Comment: So? $a_n$ tends to $a$...That's the question. I agree it suffices to prove it when $a_n$ tends to $0$. But that's all. You still have to prove something. And the proof is not easier when the limit of $a_n$ is $0$.

Comment: You can make $a_n-a $ less than epsilon.

Comment: That's what I say. You have to prove something. And again, it does not make it easier to bring this back to the $0$ case.

Comment: For instance, proving that $f(x)$ is continuous at $x_0$ is equivalent to proving that $f(x+x_0)$ at $0$.

Comment: Well, I don't. Personal tastes...that's not really important. The fact that you haven't proven anything, sorry to say that, is more annoying.

Comment: Much simpler, really? The translation from $a$ to $0$ is trivial. The proof of the equality in either case is easy, but not trivial.

Comment: ? What particular notation did I use? Try to read through. Every step is easy.

Comment: Ok, you have a proof but extracting the meaning could be hard.But well-done!!+1

Comment: Thanks, what do you suggest I make more explicit? I like using this characterization of $\liminf$ and $\limsup$, because there is no more tedious $\epsilon$ manipulation.

Comment: it is fine in fact..