# Show that $ \limsup x_n ≤ \limsup y_n$ and $\liminf x_n ≤ \liminf y_n$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, limsup-and-liminf

Let $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ be bounded sequences such that $x_n ≤ y_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Show that $\limsup x_n ≤ \limsup y_n$ and $\liminf x_n ≤ \liminf y_n$.

Comment: Assume each statement is false and prove by contradiction.

Comment: Is this prove similar to proving Sup Xn≤ Sup Yn for the first part?

Comment: Use the proposition listed [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/853239/63095) and arrive at a contradiction after assuming the negation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix an index $k$. Then
$$
m \ge k \implies x_m \le y_m \le \sup_{n \ge k} y_n.$$
Since this is true for all $m \ge k$ you have
$$ \sup_{m \ge k} x_m \le \sup_{n \ge k} y_n.$$
Now take the limit on both sides as $k \to \infty$.